# Block caching issue on twig

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, caching

I've created a new custom module and I used `Facebook SDK` to retrieve the latest post from a page.
Here is my .module file:

```
function social_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'block__feed_feed' => array(
    'render element' => 'elements',
    'template' => 'block--instagram-feed',
    'base hook' => 'block'
  )
}
function social_preprocess_block(&$variables){
 if ($variables['elements']['#configuration']['id'] === 'facebook-feed'){
   $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
     'app_id' => {$app_id},
     'app_secret' => {$app_secret},
     'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
     'default_access_token' => {$app_id}.'|'.{$app_secret},
   ]);

   $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.{$page_id}.'/posts?fields=created_time,reactions,message,comments{comment_count,like_count},likes&limit=4');
   try {
     $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
   } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
     exit;
   } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
     echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
     exit;
   }
   $posts = $response->getDecodedBody();
   $facebookposts = [];
   for($c=0 ;$c<$posts_no ;$c++){
     if(isset($posts['data'][$c]['reactions'])){
       $likes_count = count($posts['data'][$c]['reactions']['data']);
     }
     else{
       $likes_count = 0;
     }
     if(isset($posts['data'][$c]['comments'])){
       $comments_count = count($posts['data'][$c]['comments']['data']);
     }
     else{
       $comments_count = 0;
     }
     array_push($facebookposts,['post_text'=>$posts['data'][$c]['message'],'likes_count'=>$likes_count,'comments_count'=>$comments_count]);
   }
   $variables['elements']['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
   $variables['fbposts'] = $facebookposts;
   $variables['likes_comments'] = $likes_comments;
 }
}
```

and my block plugin code:

```
public function build() {
  \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
  return array(
    '#markup' => ' ',
    '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0,],
  );
}
```

and this is my block template file:

```
<ul>
{% for post in fbposts %}
 <li>
  <div class="facebook">{{post.post_text}}</div>
    <div class="likes-comments">
     <span id="comments">{{post.comments_count}}</span>
     <span id="likes">{{post.likes_count}}</span>
    </div>
  </li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now my problem is that the code is working perfectly, but when a new post is added it will not change on the website unless I clear the cache!!!
I tried to give the block `'#cache' => ['max-age' => 0,]` but it didn't work, I tried `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` on the `hook_preprocess_block` but id didn't work too.

What shall I do?

Comment: Some additional recommendations: Not caching that at all seems quite problematic actually, it means every single request to your site has to wait on the external API. Why not cache it for 5 or 10 minutes, I assume your facebook page doesn't change *that* fast? You can also use getCacheMaxAge() and return 0 there, then you don't have to print content. I'd recommend putting the logic in the block and sub array keys, then you can access it as e.g. fbposts. You could also either make a template for them all as suggested or make a template for one fbpost and then show them as a #theme item_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to render the content `build()` returns:

*block.html.twig:*

```
...

{{ content }}
```

Even if it's only an empty markup string. Otherwise the cache max-age can't bubble up.

A better approach would be to return from `build()` a custom template, which you use for the html markup instead of the block template. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-from-custom-module

Then you don't need a preprocess hook and caching works with the default block template.

Comment: thanks!!! it worked, maybe i spend 2 days for this xD
and i think i'll use your approach.
thanks again ;)